# output resistance of discrete amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, resistance, npn

I have the three-stage amplifier below. I am interested in finding the output resistance of it. Just wanna check if am doing it correctly? Thanks

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCscbT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Analysis:
\begin{equation}
i_o=i_2-i_1\\i_1=i_{b3}+g_{m3}v_{\pi 3}\\i_o=i_2-i_{b3}-g_{m3}v_{\pi 3}\\i_o=\frac{v_o}{2.4k\Omega }-\frac{\left(v_{\pi 3}-v_o\right)}{r_{\pi 3}+5.6k\Omega }-g_{m3}v_{\pi 3}\\v_{\pi }=-v_o\\i_o=\frac{v_o}{2.4k\Omega \:}-\frac{\left(-v_o-v_o\right)}{r_{\pi \:3}+5.6k\Omega \:}-g_{m3}\left(-v_o\right)\\i_o=\frac{v_o}{2.4k\Omega \:}+\frac{\left(2v_o\right)}{r_{\pi \:3}+5.6k\Omega \:}+g_{m3}\left(v_o\right)\\g_{m3}=77.6m\left(\frac{A}{V}\right)\\R_o=\frac{v_o}{i_o}=12.7\Omega 
\end{equation}

Comment: How are you doing it? What load current is planned?

Comment: You need to add a large capacitor in series with the V3 voltage source.

Comment: How much do you recommend@G36

Comment: try 10mF at first

Comment: Correct! That is exactly the answer I was supposed to get!! thank you very much

Comment: @G36 can you please post an answer to help me with hand calculations analysis. For some reason I always get 12.7 ohms

Comment: In LTspice or in your hand calculations?

Comment: @G36 in hand calculations. For some reason I always get 12.7 ohm

Comment: Show us your work

Comment: @G36, I added the hand calculations. Please advice me on my mistakes. Thank you

Comment: I do not like your expression for Ib3 in the fourth line. And v_p3i is not equal to -Vo

Comment: And to simplify the calculation remove Re3 from your small signal model. Because Re3 is in parallel with Vo. So you can add Re3 later on after you find the resistance seen from the emitter terminal into BJT.

Comment: @G36 can you please advice an expression for vpi3?

Comment: The voltage divider equation is the answer vpi3 = -Vo x rpi3/(Rc2 + rpi3)

Comment: That was exactly where my mistake was at. Fixed. Thanks a bunch

Comment: So the answer is?

Answer (score 2):

Update: if you are still having issues, remember that the DC design must be proper to get linear AC gain. The intermediate stages need proper impedance optimization for gain and DC bias and that has not been Done here.  Emitter DC drops are too high and input impedance too low so extra emitter R’s are needed and lower existing values.

Emitter followers can only source current while Re sinks current. (Like LDO’s)

\$Zout = \dfrac{R_{C2}} {h_{FE3}}||R_{E3}\$
For AC coupled output to a load , looking back into  Zout, a negative voltage now sources current from the external cap swing sinks current and if this exceeds I(Re3)
for
and = Re for -ve voltage.

Ignoring base emitter resistance etc.

Note this design is poor due to lack of active push-pull outputs. e.g. Op Amps have these. THis makes the negative supply rather useless.